# What is the difference of meaning between "conserve" and "save"?

Tags: meaning

While I was reading my assignment, I wandered that the difference of meaning between the word 'Conserve' and 'Save' because, in Korean, the meanings of the words are same. I want to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Conserve - Conserve usually applies to things that are endangered or low in number

> We must conserve our resources.

Save - Save can be used in rescue situations plus for things you want to collect. It also behaves like conserve but usually to bigger "objects."

> I saved him from drowning.
>
> I saved up some money.
>
> We must save our ecosystems.

Note we don't usually say:

> We must conserve our ecosystems

because ecosystems are larger objects that contain resources.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but I don't think it would be at all strange or unusual to use the term "conserve our ecosystems".

Comment: I guess so. I think "protect our ecosystems" is the best way and maybe most common.

Comment: Couldn't conserve also mean "keep in existing state" or "use wisely"?

Comment: Yes, those options definitely capture the idea of conserving.

Answer (score 2):

*Save* has a couple different meanings, one of which is similar to *conserve*.

> Let's save the water we have.
>
> Let's conserve the water we have.

*Save* can also mean "to rescue", "to tell a computer to commit X to persistent storage", in addition "to set aside/put away/reserve for later use."  *Conserve* won't have either of the first two meanings.

If the thing being saved/conserved is a single object that is consumed all at once, or money, then *save* is typically the appropriate term.  If you have a bunch of X and are trying to use as few as possible to make sure you have more X for later, *conserve* describes it, but so does *save*.

*Conserve* can also mean "over the long term, to take care of for future use or generations," e.g. *we must conserve the environment for future generations.*